# Are there slanguages counter to “puff piece”?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I was interested in two word”, “puff piece” and “on the dance floor” both of which are shown in quotes in Maureen Dowd’s article titled “Reince is right” in August 7 New York times.
http://www.nytimes.com/2013/08/07/opinion/dowd-reince-is-right.html?hp

It reads:

> "Films can dramatically alter the way famous people are viewed, making
>   them cooler, more glamorous, more sympathetic — and the reverse.
>   Clever filmmakers can offer up delicious soufflés of propaganda and
>   storytelling, putting a new imprint on the historical record.  (The
>   chairman of the Republican National Committee) Reince Priebus has
>   complained to NBC and CNN executives about plans for what he calls
>   **Hillary Clinton “puff pieces” while Hillary is “on the dance floor.”**

We call ‘puff piece’ a ‘lantern (holer) article’ – 提灯記事 in Japanese by comparing the article and news a meek servant carrying a lantern ahead of his master and guiding him on the street in the evening.

I'm interested in the opposite expression. Are there colloquial expressions counter to “puff piece” that lets down / harms public figures’ reputation through media?

Comment: I think puff piece means something different than what you think it means.  The "puff" metaphor refers to the "fillingness" of the news, not the effect on the reputation - that is, a puff piece has no actual content (e.g., a story about a politician's love of dogs or their favorite color).  That said, the usual purpose is to boost the subject's reputation, but that's inconsequential to the word "puff piece".

Comment: Did you have a question about "on the dance floor" which I find a delightful idiom I have not heard before but which I guess means "while she is interesting" or "in the spotlight"

Comment: Was the rather wonderful portmanteau *slanguage* deliberate?

Comment: @mplungjan. I interpreted ‘be on the dance floor’ as ‘be active / watched by spectators / be in the limelight.’ So I didn’t dare to ask the meaning. But I was drawn to the fact that Dowds introduced both ‘puff piece’ and ‘be on the dance floor’ with quotation marks, which led me to suspect neither expression is very common one.

Comment: Ah, sorry I did not read the actual article until now. I see the quotes as quotes. Meaning she is talking about Reince Priebus and his use of, I quote, "on the dance floor", so I think they are just that: Words quoted from his complaints

Comment: The story is told of William Randolph Hearst, the newspaper magnate, who upon being impressed with the ministry/preaching of evangelist Billy Graham gave his writers a succinct order:  "Puff Graham!"  In other words, give Billy Graham favorable, complimentary, complete coverage in the media, and thereby enhancing Graham's reputation and credibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extremely critical written article is sometime called a *[hatchet job](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hatchet-job?q=hatchet%20job)*

> a fierce written attack on someone or their work:
>   *she does hatchet jobs, not reviews*

It also might be called a *[smear](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smear)*

> a usually unsubstantiated charge or accusation against a person or organization —often used attributively *a smear campaign, a smear job*

And it might be referred to as *[character assassination](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/character-assassination)*

> the act of deliberately attempting to destroy a person's reputation by defamatory remarks

Answer (score 2):

I think the best word for the job is [muckraking](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/muckraking):

> the action of searching out and publicizing scandal about famous people

(The term is also associated to a period of journalism in the United States, see [Wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muckraker) for more information.)

I have found some related, but less apt terms:

[*Dig the dirt*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dig?q=dig+dirt#dig__26). Not exclusive to journalism, but quite strongly related.

Having a look through [The News Manual's Glossary](http://www.thenewsmanual.net/Resources/glossary.html), I saw the term *[defamation](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/defamation?q=defamation)*, although that's not exclusive to news reports.

There is also the term *gutter journalism*:

> A derogatory term for media which use sensational reporting without concern for the harm it will do individuals.

Although that type of reporting doesn't have to cause harm.